# Javascript Variable Undefined - Local Issue?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>CCG Sim</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            Enter Decklist:<br>
            <textarea id="txtar_decklist" cols="1" rows="100"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Create Deck" onclick="CreateDeck()"> 
        </form>
        <button type="button" onclick="DrawCard()">Draw Card</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var decklist = [];

function CreateDeck(){
   var deckform = document.getElementById("txtar_decklist").value.split('\n');
   var stats = [];
   for (var n = 0; n < deckform.length; n++){
       if (deckform[n] != ""){
           stats = deckform[n].split(',');
           for (var x = 0; x < parseInt(stats[0],10); x++){
               decklist.push({Name:     stats[1],
                              Color:    stats[2], 
                              Type:     stats[3],
                              Subtype:  stats[4], 
                              Level:    stats[5],
                              Attack:   stats[6],
                              Defense:  stats[7],
                              Drawn:    false});
            }
        }
    }
};

function DrawCard(){
    var randomcard = 0;
    var carddrawn = false;
    while (carddrawn == false){
        randomcard = (Math.floor(Math.random() * decklist.length + 1)) - 1;
        if (decklist[randomcard].Drawn == false){
            alert(JSON.stringify(decklist[randomcard]));
            decklist[randomcard].Drawn = true;
            carddrawn = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Problem:

Variable Decklist is undefined in each function. Of course the first function can create an array of objects for Decklist, but its value doesn't continue to exist later for the second function to use (it's simply undefined in the second).

Basically a user will insert a list into a form and the CreateDeck() function will (ideally) create an array of objects from the supplied list. Later, whenever the user wants, he or she clicks the Draw Card button which calls DrawCard(). This second function can't access the value of Decklist because it's undefined inside of this.

What am I not getting here? Any tips?

Comment: `(Math.floor(Math.random() * decklist.length + 1)) - 1` seems like it’s just `Math.floor(Math.random() * decklist.length)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show the error in your console and describe how to produce it.

Comment: You can also use https://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the error you're getting. Once posted there, everyone can reproduce the error you are experiencing.

Comment: One issue is that you are submitting a form on clicking Create Deck - as you have no `action` for the form, the result is that the page posts to the current URL - which would basically refresh the page - so, therefore `decklist` will be empty ... is it `decklist` that is undefined or `decklist[randomcard]` ? Is there any reason you need to use a form at all?

Comment: Decklist is undefined. So I should just avoid using a form in this case? I'm still quite new to everything, so my apologies if this is super simple.

Comment: @TylerG: How are you determining that `decklist` is undefined?

Comment: Chrome development tools and stepping into the code. The array doesn't have a value once the second function is called.

Comment: @JaromandaX I removed the form from the HTML document and instead relied solely on the text area. It worked! Thank you for pointing out that issue. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the whole code is perfect. But you have to remove semicolon at the end of each function closing..